# Directory path issue in unix platform

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new in java. I have property file as below.

```
LOG_PATH = /export/home/mydev/log
LOG_FILE = MyApplication.log
```

And im using LOG_PATH for log location and LOG_FILE for log file name. jar file running in UNIX platform. My expected log name is MyApplication.log. But actually getting "log\MyApplication.log"

```
File log_file = new File(logLocation, logFileName);
log_file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you print out `log_file` and show us what it prints?

Comment: what do you mean by `But actually getting "log\MyApplication.log"`

Comment: Can you show us how to load the properties?

Comment: When you write `log\MyApplication.log` you mean your file is created in a different location than it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your working path is /export/home/mydev (home of Java project), so the filename is log/MyApplication.log. That's correct (beacause you creaded it by /export/home/mydev/log + MyApplication.log).
The only mystery thing is the backslash istead of slash on UNIX.